# Always getting - Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate the logging in for one of our applications and trying to click on 'Reporting' (as highlighted in yellow). When i inspect it in firefox, it says its an anchor web element (with this version of firefox i'm not able to install firebug/firepath). This page loads immediately after i enter the username/password and click the 'Submit' button on the previous page. The script always gives me error that 'element not visible'. I tried even explicit wait for that element by using the xpath "//ul[@id='mainnav-menu']/li[2]/a" or "//ul[@id='mainnav-menu' and @class='list-group']/li[2]/a". Could you please help to determine why i'm getting this exception all the time. Basically what i'm trying to do is click on this element which will show 2 links once that arrow beside it expands. i need to click on the 1st child element after it shows up.

[Please see the HTML code portion for the element from the application in the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsQOf.jpg)

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: You are required to post an example of the code that shows the problem here: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The error means that element exists (html is loaded), but not visible. It may be out of visible part of the screen or because of java script effects.

Comment: It may be also because the element is belong to Select type, but you try to click your option as a normal WebElement.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. i'm still struggling to get this element visible and click on it. It is not of a select type. it is visible on screen to me. If it is rendered invisible due to javascript how do i fix that. also the interesting this the left part of the page has the additional 'Reporting' link on this page along with the 'Help' link. in the previous page it just had the 'Help' link and i was able to click that. Only when i come to this page i'm constantly getting the error 'element not visible'. not sure why.